# Javascript get content by data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a body with data-id tag and im trying to access its html content. For simple textboxes with id .val() works fine. But for this particular, I dont have id only data-id. How can I access its content?

```
    <body data-id="myid"> 
      some html code is here 
    </body>
```

i want to access its content, i tried following

```
$('body[data-id="myid"]').val();
$('body[data-id="myid"]').value();
$('body[data-id="myid"]').html();
```

only get "undefined" at best

Comment: `var allHTML = $('body').html();` works.

Comment: this body is not the only one that is on page.. this is body of "tinymce". I need to make sure I call correct body

Comment: Is it in an iframe? Although it's technically possible to have two `<body>` statements I would highly discourage doing so.

Comment: yes its in iframe. I have no choice but to have it there. It is generated by tinymce

Comment: If it's in an iframe then it has it's own `<body>` statement.  You should be able to get access to your own `<body>` with no issues. If you are trying to access tinymce's body, I recommend looking at their website to see what is available.

Comment: how can I access it ? I mean.. can I say in javascript #iframeid>body> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another possible solution:

```
$('*[data-id="myid"]').html();
```

**Edit**

If you are using tinyMCE maybe you are trying to get the body element of tinyMCE's textarea too early, when it is not fully loaded, try this:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback

Comment: So maybe that content isn't loaded yet

Comment: Its a tinymce textarea. I write something inside of it. It should be something

Comment: Which version of tinyMCE are you using?

Comment: version 4.1.9 (2015-03-10)

Comment: Sounds like it's in an iframe, try something like `$('*[data-id="myid"]', $('iframe').contents()).html();`

Comment: gwing33 it worked! thank you sooooo much! you saved me soo much troubles

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$('body[data-id="myid"]').html()
```